# How to define type function output by condition in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to define type for output of my function, I want to set condition between `string` and `number` types depend on `toNumberIfNeeded` flag, suppose if `toNumberIfNeeded` is true then this function will return an number type and vice versa return string type. How I can do it?

```
interface Options {
    uppercase?: boolean;
    filterSpecialChars?: boolean;
    toNumberIfNeeded?: boolean;
}

export const textTransformer = (text: string, options?: Options) => {

   const { uppercase, filterSpecialChars, toNumberIfNeeded} = options || {};
   // my handle logics code

   return toNumberIfNeeded ? parseInt(text) : text;
}
```

Example what I expected:

```
   textTransformer('hello'); // return string type
   textTransformer('123', { toNumberIfNeeded: true }); // return number type
```

Comment: I'm certainly no expert but what I would attempt is to declare to option types:  `interface NumericalOptions { ..., toNumberIfNeeded: true }` and `interface StringOptions { ..., toNumberIfNeeded: false}`.  Then I can declare overloads in the .d.ts file: `export function textTransformer(text: string, options: NumericalOptions) => number;` and `export function textTransformer(text:string, options: StringOptions) => string`.

Comment: @JoséRamírez `true` and `false` value are incorrect syntax in interface typescript

Comment: I'm pretty sure that true and false are valid TypeScript types.  Maybe they are just not accepted in interfaces.  Try declaring it as a type, not an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refactor `textTransformer()` to accept a generic parameter and use a conditional type to check whether `toNumberIfNeeded` is `true` or `false`. I don't think TypeScript is able to narrow down the return value automatically. You'll have to use Type Assertion for that otherwise the return type is inferred as `string | number`.

```
interface Options {
  uppercase: boolean;
  filterSpecialChars: boolean;
  toNumberIfNeeded: boolean;
}

export const textTransformer = <T extends Options>(
  text: string,
  options?: T
): T["toNumberIfNeeded"] extends true ? number : string => {
  const {uppercase, filterSpecialChars, toNumberIfNeeded} =
    options || {};
  // my handle logics code

  return (toNumberIfNeeded ? parseInt(text) : text) as ReturnType<
    typeof textTransformer
  >;
};

textTransformer("hello"); // inferred as string
textTransformer("123", {
  toNumberIfNeeded: true,
  uppercase: false,
  filterSpecialChars: false
}); // inferred as number
```

Comment: Here are the TS issues: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014 (discussions confirm either type assertion or overload is needed)